# How can I use a variable in getRange()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to change the row number to a variable. Either to the value that's in the cell 'Q1' or to be one higher every time I use the function.

This is the function without changing the row number. In my wanted outcome all of the $B$3 and $D$3 would be $B$(Q1) and $D$(Q1).

```
function Nextgame() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Z3').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=10^IF(OR($D$3=R3,$B$3=R3),if(XLOOKUP(1,$U$3:$U$32,$R$3:$R$32,0,0,1)=$B$3,XLOOKUP($B$3,$R$3:$R$32,$S$3:$S$32,8,0,1),XLOOKUP($D$3,$R$3:$R$32,$S$3:$S$32,9,0,1)/$P$1),(-10))');
}
```

I tried replacing the row number with ('Q1'), (+1), & Q1 in A1 and R1C1 notation. Everytime it just wouldn't run due to the format not being consistent with A1 or R1C1

Comment: You might like to use [getRange().offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) or [getRange(row,column))](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Comment: for(let i =1; i< data.length; i++) { sheet.getRange("Q" + i);...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a variable.  At the end I increment the value at Q1.

```
function Nextgame() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
  let range = sheet.getRange("Q1");
  let value = range.getValue();

  let formula = "=10^IF(OR($D$"+value+"=R3,$B$"+value+"=R3)";
  formula = formula+",if(XLOOKUP(1,$U$3:$U$32,$R$3:$R$32,0,0,1)=$B$"+value;
  formula = formula+",XLOOKUP($B$"+value+",$R$3:$R$32,$S$3:$S$32,8,0,1)"
  formula = formula+",XLOOKUP($D$"+value+",$R$3:$R$32,$S$3:$S$32,9,0,1)/$P$1),(-10))";

  sheet.getRange("Z3").setFormula(formula);
  range.setValue(value+1);
}
```